# Table prefix in pyrocms

Tags: php, mysql, pyrocms

I am working on a custom multiple delete in pyrocms module,how to use delete in model
my code:

```
 protected $_table = 'accounts';
    public function mulDelete($muldelete) 
        {   
            $sql = 'delete from ' . $this->_table . ' where id IN('.$muldelete. ')';
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        }
```

> but    $this->_table is returning accounts instead of
>   username_accounts,how to check username table prefix in from clause in
>   pyrocms

Comment: why you are not adding it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'delete from ' .'username_'. $this->_table . ' where id IN('.$muldelete. ')';
```

or

```
protected $_table = 'username_accounts';
```

or dyamically

```
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    echo $CI->db->dbprefix;
```

Comment: $this->db->dbprefix . $this->_table will be more precise